# Unable to perform registerDevice after an unregisterDevice when using the cordova bms-push plugin

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I've recently updated to the latest version of the [bms-push](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push) cordova plugin.

I've noticed a strange behaviour when trying to use the `unregisterDevice` function of the plugin. When this function is called, seems like it becomes impossible to perform a `registerDevice` afterwards. When calling the `registerDevice`function neither the success callback nor the failure callback is fired.

This issue is observed on iOS only.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: I'm currently recreating.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to register and unregister several times using this code:

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        var appGUID = "MY APP GUID";
        var clientSecret = "MY CLIENT SECRET";

        BMSClient.initialize(BMSClient.REGION_US_SOUTH);
        BMSPush.initialize(appGUID,clientSecret);

        var failure = function(failureResponse) {
            alert("Failed: " + failureResponse);
        };

        var success = function(response) {
            alert("Success: " + response);
        };

        var firstSuccess = function(successResponse) {
            BMSPush.unregisterDevice(secondSuccess, failure)
        };

        var secondSuccess = function(successResponse) {
            BMSPush.registerDevice({"userId":"you"}, thirdSuccess, failure);
        };

        var thirdSuccess = function(successResponse) {
            BMSPush.unregisterDevice(fourthSuccess, failure)
        };

        var fourthSuccess = function(successResponse) {
            BMSPush.registerDevice({"userId":"you"}, fifthSuccess, failure);
        };

        var fifthSuccess = function(successResponse) {
            alert("Third success: " + successResponse);
        };

        BMSPush.registerDevice({"userId":"you"}, firstSuccess, failure);
    },

    registerNotificationsCallback: function() {
        var showNotification = function(notif) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(notif));
        };

        BMSPush.registerNotificationsCallback(showNotification);
    },

    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```